# How to apply effects to only newly appended nodes (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am loading in html via AJAX and appending it to a DIV but I want to be able to select the newly loaded in html and apply a hide().fadeIn() to elements in that newly appended html.

Current function looks something like this

```
wall = new Object();

wall.showWall = function (options) {
    // Use this to initiate the comment wall
    $.ajax({
        url: "activity_results.html?"+options,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#comments .loader").hide(); // The wall's comment spinner
            requestStuff.showResponse(); // Trigger the addComment function
            if (!options){ // Make sure we are not paging
                wall.showMore();
            }
            $("#comments").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });

}
```

When new html gets loaded into #comments I want to be able to only fade in those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending to `#comments` create a hidden div inside of it and append it to that div.

Then `fadeIn` that hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(html).appendTo("#comments").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass html content as a selector to $... really?

Comment: Unfortunately the effect does not get applied like this, it just appends and displays immediately.